# Ajax call caching using Litespeed cache plugin in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, caching, litespeed, admin-ajax

I have an issue with caching ajax calls,
I am using ajax calls to count my post views and because of my high traffic I am not able to hit the database directly, so I want to store post views in cache and then save them in database on minutely intervals.
The problem is wp_cache_add() is overridden by Litespeed Cache plugin and in this plugin's function there is a function call before storing cache data which checks for defined('WP_ADMIN') which is always true in admin-ajax.
So how can I bypass this without enabling admin cache in this plugin settings?

Comment: Have you tried to turn on `Settings > Advance > Object Cache > Cache Wp-Admin`? It will allow you to use wp_cache_add on `defined('WP_ADMIN')`. But in fact, this is a bug, you can follow this post: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/solution-for-image-optm-hash-does-not-match-error/ to remove the `_can_cache` condition.

Comment: Turning on that option will cache wp-admin area which I don't want to do, I only want to cache that specific ajax call

Comment: Then you need to remove rows 453 – 455 in plugin/litespeed-cache/inc/object.class.php:

`if ( ! $this->_can_cache() ) {
 return null ;
}`

this bug will be fixed after v3.0